# Om/Clojurescript: Issue rendering a reset application state

Tags: clojurescript, om

I am trying to display a component with om, as soon as the data needed for this widget arrives. I came up with the following (roughly):

```
(def data (atom     {}))                                                               

(go (let [response (<! (http/get "../rest/ds" ))]                               
  (reset! data (:result (:body response)))))

(om/root
  (fn [app owner]                                                                  
    (reify
     om/IInitState
     (init-state [_]
       (prn "(1) returning initial state now")
       {:text "Hello world!"})
     om/IRenderState 
     (render-state [this state]                                                   
        (prn state) ; <-- here: not the state that I reset! before but the original state
        (do-something ...))))                                                  
  data
  {:target (. js/document (getElementById "app"))})
```

It seems that `state` within `render-state` is never what I set it with `reset!` although a re-rendering seems to be triggered. Am I using something wrong here? when directly accessing `@data` in `render-state` it shows the proper value that I set with `reset!`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The state in `(prn state)` is the component state. The atom `data` is the application state, which in your component you have called `app`.

```
(om/root
  (fn [app owner]  ; <- `app` is the application state                                                              
    (reify
     om/IInitState
     (init-state [_]
       (prn "(1) returning initial state now")
       {:text "Hello world!"})
     om/IRenderState 
     (render-state [this state]                                                   
        (prn app) ; <- refer to application state instead
        (do-something ...))))                          
  data
  {:target (. js/document (getElementById "app"))})
```